# How to apply filter AND select top most matches in JSONPath

Tags: json, jsonpath

I want to filter by some expression and select only the first five matches to that expression.

http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/ shows how to do a filter on a value:

$..book[?(@.price<10)]

And how to filter out only the first matches:

$..book[:2]

But how do I combine the two? I've tried various approaches, but cant seem to find anything that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jsonpath-plus, this can be retrieved by:

```
var result = JSONPath({json: sample, path: '$..book[?(@property <= 5 && @.price<10)]'});
```

This is because `@property` here is a custom feature of jsonpath-plus for getting the current object property, in this case, the array index.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j59uktso/1/)

I think the original JSONPath spec, while a great start, was somewhat under-specified, which is why it was enhanced and has been better documented at https://github.com/s3u/JSONPath . However, there are other implementations, at least in other languages, so there may be some discrepancies in how this can be done (if at all) in other implementations.

(Disclaimer: I'm involved with the jsonpath-plus project.)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I'm limited to Jayways 2.1 implementation (I'm using the JSONPath jmeter plugin). I'll accept your answer unless someone posts a better one soon. I guess I'll have to do a workaround in code!

Comment: @brett-zamir Any idea why the most basic functionalities where never added to jsonPath? I kinda keep struggling with it and there are so many limitations that it's literally unusable, as not even simple xpath equivalents to `parties[role='SU'].[1].country` are impossible to do. `$.partiies[?()@.role == "SU"][0].country` just won't work. Being unable to index an query result (result of the first `[...]`) makes it unusable in 98% of all cases sadly, not even supporting 5% of XPath scenarios

Comment: JSONPath just wasn't advanced. I don't expect it had anything to do with a lack of desire to see the features. It looks like you have an error in your filter, so I would suggest adding an issue and linking to it here for your problem because it may be possible and jsonpath-plus and other implementations can do some more than jsonpath can. See https://cburgmer.github.io/json-path-comparison/ for an effort to standardize. While it is a different syntax, I found jsonata rather robust. RQL was another attempt at something robust but not sure about how well-maintained its JS implementations are.